# Using Azure Icons and Boxes on Azure DevOps with Mermaid

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following mermaid diagram, which I have validated on [mermaid.live](https://mermaid.live) and intend to use it on the Wiki section of Azure DevOps:

```
sequenceDiagram
    box Container;
    participant A as Container A;
    participant B as Container B;
    end;
```

I know that the wiki for Azure DevOps has support for mermaid diagrams, but for some reason it doesn't render if I include the `box` block above. Is this a version problem? If so, is there a way to update it mermaid to the latest version?

I also would like to know if it is possible to use Azure Architecture icons within these diagrams.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a lot of syntax for mermaid is not supported in Azure DevOps. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops) where is stated:

> Not all syntax in the content linked below for diagram types works in Azure DevOps. For example, we don't support most HTML tags, Font Awesome, flowchart syntax (graph used instead), or LongArrow ---->.

I've tested your syntax as well and I can confirm it wouldn't load here as well, only without the box.